# Mysql php - how to save a file without spaces and special characters

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

on my website i'm using a form to ulpoad the images of the users that compiles that form. 
Then, that image should be automatically displayed through a simple query and php, and it just worked fine until i've discovered that i ca'nt display images that has spaces or special characters in the name. 
So the point is: how can i solve this issue?

To display the image i just at first  save it in a folder, and save its name in the database in a table, im using phpmyadmin. 
Thanks to all

Comment: What do you call special characters? ([see](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/)]. I think you have to build an exaustive list of allowed characters first.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you rename the picture before uploading. You can remove special characters with function

> preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

read more in doc [enter link description here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the name in upload folder is matching with the name of the picture it could be because you're not inserting "Special characters" this might help:

```
 mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$NameOfThePicture);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
Check the documentation.